# union and order by not working in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, union, limit

I'm trying to union two tables with same exact column names but no shared columns and then pick the top 10 results. However, the results aren't reflecting the top 10 results.

I've tried this

```
Select a,b from table 1
UNION
Select a,b from table 2
ORDER by b DESC Limit 10
```

but the code isn't showing me the top 10 highest quantity from column b. Please let me know what I'm missing here. Thank you!!

Comment: Please create a fiddle that allows to reproduce your issue. Then share the url. I wanted to replicate the unexpected behaviour. But it works as intended: https://dbfiddle.uk/9LN8AAvZ

Answer (score 0):

The below query works as expected and is returning the top 10 rows in descending order from both tables:

```
select first_name,last_name from actor
union
select first_name,last_name from customer
order by last_name desc limit 10
```